# putexcel using R1C1 notation

Tags: reference, cell, export-to-excel, stata

As from the official documentation of Stata "putexcel" procedure uses standard excel cell notation i.e. D25 instead of R25C4. If I only know column number is it possible to convert it to letters in my script?

Or is it possible to increment column names?

Comment: Perhaps you can show us an example on what you intent to do. I am having difficulty understanding this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an undocumented Mata function `numtobase26()` that converts column numbers to Excel's column letters. For example, if you want to know what the 27th column will be called in Excel you can type in Stata:

```
. mata : numtobase26(27)
AA
```

Comment: Thank you very helpful in order to capture the results in Stata I used `getmata st_var=mata_var`